# SOAPUI and testrail integration

Tags: api, web-services, integration, soapui, testrail

Can anyone help me with the Integration of **SOAPUI and Testrail**. If there is any Youtube or any other tutorials please share
After execution of testcases from soapui the status should get updated in testrail

Answer (score 1):

https://discuss.gurock.com/t/how-to-log-into-testrail-api-with-soapui/10849

Can u try this??

Also Test rail api is exposed.. you can take the code and convert that code in to jar put in to soapui/bin/ext folder.  Now u write a groovy code to use that library

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at ([Agiletestware Firefly](https://www.agiletestware.com/firefly) plugin for ReadyAPI (SoapUI Pro).
It integrates with ReadyAPI and upload test results (including HTTP/SOAP request and response) into TestRail for each run of your tests in ReadyAPI.
Here is the link to the documentation: https://www.agiletestware.com/docs/firefly-docs/en/latest/

Disclaimer: Agiletestware Firefly is a commercial product and I'm a developer of this product